# How to catch all React Native exception in Android App?

Tags: android, react-native

in React Native source code DevSupportManagerImpl.java have this code:

```
  @Override
  public void handleException(Exception e) {
      if (mIsDevSupportEnabled) {
          if (e instanceof JSException) {
              FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "Exception in native call from JS", e);
              // TODO #11638796: convert the stack into something useful
              showNewError(e.getMessage() + "\n\n" + ((JSException) e).getStack(), new StackFrame[] {},
                 JSEXCEPTION_ERROR_COOKIE, ErrorType.JS);
          } else {
              showNewJavaError(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
      } else {
          mDefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
      }
  }
```

when mIsDevSupportEnabled is false(publish version), how to catch exception in java code?

Comment: such as, when i load a customer bundle file from server, the init may be crash(program jump to handleException else), because the customer bundle file maybe bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think Crashlytics should be used . For better understanding , check the following conversation in github

[Handling React Native Exceptions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1665)

Comment: TKS,but i want to catch init exception(hotload bundle file), when catched this exception that will jump to web page.